# Push/synchronize data to server from clients

Tags: .net, client-server, data-synchronization

I have a problem with synchronizing/reporting client processing to server. The concept of this is one central server on which is stored data of many my customers eg. I sell applications to some companies and all of them has own departments. All of this companies has website on which they can log in and check eg. warehouse products amount, sell progress etc. Department has desktop application (internet connection only per request/ cheaper) and eg. only daily is reporting warehouse and other things state.

If someone knows some framework, library, pattern to do this I would be grateful.
What I was thinking at first it was Sync Framework but the database is one for all client/companies. Then something about WCF and sending only reports about processing (eg. what was sold, warehouse products amount) but now I'm not sure If this is good step. One other idea was to use event sourcing but my client apps already are done and this would be overkill.

PS. in future maybe we would like to send some data back to client apps.

Answer (score 0):

Expose a server endpoint either through a separate web service application or dynamically from your server application via wcf.  client connects to endpoint, transfers data, you process data, done...

you'll need to make sure you have a domain name or static ip address so your clients can know where to connect to said services.  if the client/server is sold as a package to a customer, you'll need to have that server address / endpoint configurable so the client can change it and test the connection.

as far as eventually receiving data back from the server, you can again have the client expose an endpoint via wcf programmatically and perhaps send the endpoint details to the server via a "hello" call to the server when the client starts up.  the server will need to be able to queue messages for a particular client, which will entail some additional logic.